# STM32WB55 Nucleo - FUS_STATE_IMG_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: stm32, bluetooth-low-energy, bootloader

I'm beginner to electronics. I'm trying to flash stm32wb5x_BLE_HCILayer_fw.bin v1.6 using STM32CubeProgrammer but got an error "FUS_STATE_IMG_NOT_AUTHENTIC", I tried older version but got the same error. Then I hit "Firmware delete" in STM32CubeProgrammer. Now I'm getting different error "FUS_STATE_IMG_NOT_FOUND", looks like I have somehow deleted (or corrupted) wireless stack. Only thing I found related to this error is:

`If no wireless stack is installed and a delete request is sent, then the FUS returns error state informing that no wireless stack was found (FUS_STATE_IMG_NOT_FOUND).`

I'm not even sure when I started to get this new error.

Start address that I have used is 0x080dc000, tried with "First install" checked/unchecked. I'm using ST-LINK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it, got a clue from a colleague and this thread https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000Ay9bkd/stm32wb-fus-update-fail-from-101-to-102. Here is what I did:

1. Deleted the firmware
2. Loaded stm32wb5x_FUS_fw_1_0_2.bin at 0x080EC000. stm32wb5x_FUS_fw.bin (v1.0.1) didn’t work first time. After I loaded 1.0.2, I was able to load 1.0.1.

After this I was able to flash "stm32wb5x_BLE_HCILayer_fw.bin".

Apparently the original issue was that the stock firmware had old key and it could not verify if "stm32wb5x_BLE_HCILayer_fw.bin" was valid.